# what to include in Angular project to use Layout Material?

Tags: angularjs

i want to use

```
<div layout="row" layout-align="space-around center">
    <div style="width:200px;background-color:#00f">left</div>
    <div style="width:300px;background-color:#0f0" ng-include="'views/home/interests.html'"></div>
    <div style="width:500px;background-color:#f00">right</div>
</div>
```

as defined in this page https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/alignment

What i must include in my project, is there an Angular-Layout.js to install with bower ?

It should be aligned in a Row, but here the result :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is a part of the Angular Material library, you must include that library in your page.

```
<!-- Angular Material Library -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>
```

See: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/getting-started

Comment: Thanks, i added it, and i add requires 'ngAria' ,  'ngMaterial', but still not working !

Comment: oubs i forget the angular-material.min.css